# ASP.Net Cookies lost after Ajax Call (w JQuery)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax, session-cookies

I have an ASP.Net website using cookies (is being used internally in the company). But somehow my cookies get lost  after an ajax-call

On my Loginpage I set the e-mailaddress inside a cookie:

```
Response.Cookies("eUser").Value = StaticVars.EncryptMyData(email)
```

The EncryptData causes the String (containing the emailaddress to be encrypted. After the loginprocedure has been succesfully handled, I use a response.redirect to navigate to another page. I do this as follows:

```
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx")
```

On this page i read out the cookie using a method from the Statics class

```
If StaticVars.GetEmail() Is Nothing Then
....
```

The method `GetEmail()` just reads out the Cookie like this:

```
Dim Cookie As HttpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("eUser")
```

No problems so far. But when i do an internal Ajax-call (To get JSON-Data) to an ASPX-page present in the solution, then my `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("eUser")` becomes nothing

**My questions**

**1**: Are all the cookies being reset after an ajax-call?

**2**: Are the values stored in a session object restricted to current Session or are they usable even after executing ajax calls within the same application?

**3**: If the cookies are being reset, what alternatives are there around? (Except using values inside the querystring).Can i pass my cookies along with my ajax-call for instance?

Thank you for your time/patience

**Note:** Expiration-date of the cookies are 100 days into the future:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies("eUser").Expires = Date.Now.AddDays(100)
```

Comment: If your ajax target document is in a subfolder the Cookie path could be set to this folder and therefore not be useable elsewhere. Set the Path to "/".

Comment: All three files are in the same folder - login.aspx (=cookie is being set here), default.aspx (first time cookie is being used), ProductAction.aspx (= target of my ajaxcall). Although i'll note your remark, it might come in handy in the near future.